# Remove Empty Elements field and Default value in XML message using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

The Detailed specification of the requirement is, in the Request message there is a field by name IgnoreEmptyElementInd it is of boolean type. If that field is True, need to ignore the empty element fields in the request message and default values like "-111" shd be set as default value found. In Case of false, no need to delete empty elements only if default values are found it shd be notified.

My Input message is

```
<SampleUpdRq>
     <RqUID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RqUID>
     <UpdMsgRqHdr>
          <ContextRqHdr>
              <RsSelURL>111</RsSelURL>
              <NetworkTrnData>
                    <TerminalIdent>a</TerminalIdent>
                    <Name>111</Name>
              </NetworkTrnData>
              <ClientApp>
                     <Org>dweer</Org>
                     <Name>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</Name>
                     <Version>112</Version>
                     <Channel>abc</Channel>
              </ClientApp>
          </ContextRqHdr>
          <IgnoreEmptyElementInd>true</IgnoreEmptyElementInd>
     </UpdMsgRqHdr>
     <SampleKeys>
           <SampleId>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</SampleId>
           <AltSampleIdentifiers>
              <SampleIdent>
                   <SampleIdentType>-111</SampleIdentType>
                    <SampleIdentValue>ttttttt</SampleIdentValue>
              </SampleIdent>
              <SampleIdentType/>
           </AltSampleIdentifiers>
           <SampleType>
                <SampleTypeValue>MMA</SampleTypeValue>
                <SampleTypeSrc>bbc</SampleTypeSrc>
                <CommercialSampleType></CommercialSampleType>
           </SampleType>
           <CommercialSampleType>-111</CommercialSampleType>
           <COID>aaaaa</COID>
       </SampleKeys>
</SampleUpdRq>
```

If the value of IgnoreEmptyElementInd is *true*, then output shd be like

```
<SampleUpdRq>
     <RqUID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RqUID>
     <UpdMsgRqHdr>
          <ContextRqHdr>
              <RsSelURL>111</RsSelURL>
              <NetworkTrnData>
                    <TerminalIdent>a</TerminalIdent>
                    <Name>111</Name>
              </NetworkTrnData>
              <ClientApp>
                     <Org>dweer</Org>
                     <Name>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</Name>
                     <Version>112</Version>
                     <Channel>abc</Channel>
              </ClientApp>
          </ContextRqHdr>
          <IgnoreEmptyElementInd>true</IgnoreEmptyElementInd>
     </UpdMsgRqHdr>
     <SampleKeys>
           <SampleId>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</SampleId>
           <AltSampleIdentifiers>
              <SampleIdent>
                   <SampleIdentType>Default Found</SampleIdentType>
                    <SampleIdentValue>ttttttt</SampleIdentValue>
              </SampleIdent>
           </AltSampleIdentifiers>
           <SampleType>
                <SampleTypeValue>MMA</SampleTypeValue>
                <SampleTypeSrc>bbc</SampleTypeSrc>
           </SampleType>
           <CommercialSampleType>Default Found</CommercialSampleType>
           <COID>aaaaa</COID>
       </SampleKeys>
</SampleUpdRq>
```

If the value of IgnoreEmptyElementInd is *false*, then output shd be like

```
<SampleUpdRq>
     <RqUID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RqUID>
     <UpdMsgRqHdr>
          <ContextRqHdr>
              <RsSelURL>111</RsSelURL>
              <NetworkTrnData>
                    <TerminalIdent>a</TerminalIdent>
                    <Name>111</Name>
              </NetworkTrnData>
              <ClientApp>
                     <Org>dweer</Org>
                     <Name>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</Name>
                     <Version>112</Version>
                     <Channel>abc</Channel>
              </ClientApp>
          </ContextRqHdr>
          <IgnoreEmptyElementInd>false</IgnoreEmptyElementInd>
     </UpdMsgRqHdr>
     <SampleKeys>
           <SampleId>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</SampleId>
           <AltSampleIdentifiers>
              <SampleIdent>
                   <SampleIdentType>Default Found</SampleIdentType>
                    <SampleIdentValue>ttttttt</SampleIdentValue>
              </SampleIdent>
              <SampleIdentType/>
           </AltSampleIdentifiers>
           <SampleType>
                <SampleTypeValue>MMA</SampleTypeValue>
                <SampleTypeSrc>bbc</SampleTypeSrc>
            <CommercialSampleType/>
           </SampleType>
           <CommercialSampleType>Default Found</CommercialSampleType>
           <COID>aaaaa</COID>
       </SampleKeys>
</SampleUpdRq>
```

I have written XSL like this :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>     

<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]" />     

<xsl:template match="*[. = '-111']">       
  <xsl:copy>          
    <xsl:text>Default Found</xsl:text>
 </xsl:copy>    
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>          
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>    
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Really appreciate the expertise help and sorry for the confusion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first XSLT sample has `version="2.0"`, do you use an XSLT 2.0 processor? And consider to post a representative XML input sample and the corresponding result you want to create, then we can suggest the right XSLT way of solving that.

Comment: You need to define the condition that is used to delete elements. Please, edit the question and add this.

Comment: @Vinay: Does **IgnoreEmptyElementInd** apply to the whole XML document, or just the **UpdMsgRqHdr** element?

Comment: @Tim C :IgnoreEmptyElementInd will apply to the whole XML document except the **UpdMsgRqHdr** element. IgnoreEmptyElementInd will be the last element of **UpdMsgRqHdr**, so for the elements coming after IgnoreEmptyElementInd, the rule should be applied.

Comment: @Tim C: Could this be done in XSL or not??

Comment: In your expected output, the empty tags have been removed from **UpdMsgRqHdr**, but left in **SampleKeys**, which seems to be the opposite of what you are suggesting, so I am a bit confused!

Comment: @Tim C: Sorry for the confusion, what i have told you above is my query. Changed the Messages now in the input and output as well.

Comment: I've re-added my question to hopefully cope with the new requirements!

Answer (score 1):

In one of your comments you say "the elements coming after IgnoreEmptyElementInd, the rule should be applied", in which case it sounds you need to make use of the 'preceding' axis in XPath to determine the value.

So, you could extend your XSLT with this template to ignore empty nodes when **IgnoreEmptyElementInd** is set to true.

```
<xsl:template 
   match="*[not(node())][preceding::IgnoreEmptyElementInd[. = 'true']]"/>
```

So, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="*[not(node())][preceding::IgnoreEmptyElementInd[. = 'true']]"/>

   <xsl:template match="*[. = '-111']">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:text>Default Found</xsl:text>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<SampleUpdRq>
   <RqUID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RqUID>
   <UpdMsgRqHdr>
      <ContextRqHdr>
         <RsSelURL>111</RsSelURL>
         <NetworkTrnData>
            <TerminalIdent>a</TerminalIdent>
            <Name>111</Name>
         </NetworkTrnData>
         <ClientApp>
            <Org>dweer</Org>
            <Name>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</Name>
            <Version>112</Version>
            <Channel>abc</Channel>
         </ClientApp>
      </ContextRqHdr>
      <IgnoreEmptyElementInd>true</IgnoreEmptyElementInd>
   </UpdMsgRqHdr>
   <SampleKeys>
      <SampleId>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</SampleId>
      <AltSampleIdentifiers>
         <SampleIdent>
            <SampleIdentType>Default Found</SampleIdentType>
            <SampleIdentValue>ttttttt</SampleIdentValue>
         </SampleIdent>
      </AltSampleIdentifiers>
      <SampleType>
         <SampleTypeValue>MMA</SampleTypeValue>
         <SampleTypeSrc>bbc</SampleTypeSrc>
      </SampleType>
      <CommercialSampleType>Default Found</CommercialSampleType>
      <COID>aaaaa</COID>
   </SampleKeys>
</SampleUpdRq>
```

When **IgnoreEmptyElementInd** is set to 'false' the following is output instead

```
<SampleUpdRq>
   <RqUID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RqUID>
   <UpdMsgRqHdr>
      <ContextRqHdr>
         <RsSelURL>111</RsSelURL>
         <NetworkTrnData>
            <TerminalIdent>a</TerminalIdent>
            <Name>111</Name>
         </NetworkTrnData>
         <ClientApp>
            <Org>dweer</Org>
            <Name>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</Name>
            <Version>112</Version>
            <Channel>abc</Channel>
         </ClientApp>
      </ContextRqHdr>
      <IgnoreEmptyElementInd>false</IgnoreEmptyElementInd>
   </UpdMsgRqHdr>
   <SampleKeys>
      <SampleId>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</SampleId>
      <AltSampleIdentifiers>
         <SampleIdent>
            <SampleIdentType>Default Found</SampleIdentType>
            <SampleIdentValue>ttttttt</SampleIdentValue>
         </SampleIdent>
         <SampleIdentType/>
      </AltSampleIdentifiers>
      <SampleType>
         <SampleTypeValue>MMA</SampleTypeValue>
         <SampleTypeSrc>bbc</SampleTypeSrc>
         <CommercialSampleType/>
      </SampleType>
      <CommercialSampleType>Default Found</CommercialSampleType>
      <COID>aaaaa</COID>
   </SampleKeys>
</SampleUpdRq>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tim C. I have 1 more doubt, in the above XML msg deris field called IgnoreEmptyElementInd dis is of boolean type.
If the value is true of IgnoreEmptyElementInd 
=>Need to delete all the empty element fields in the message 
=>And there will be few defalut values like "1200-1-1" for Date type field and "-111" for integer type field, for elements having these values only element field shd be retained.

If the value is false
=>No need to delete the empty element fields in the message
=>Need to delete the elements with default values like mentioned above.Is it possible in XSL?

Comment: You either need to amend the original question with the full and detailed requirements, so there is no misunderstanding. If you give the full rules for how "IgnoreEmptyElementInd" works, it should be possible to do.

Comment: Changed the original question with detailed Requirements.